# Style not being applied to inner element via Style property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have got a custom control composed of many parts.
One of those parts is a `Border`.

I need to style that border from outside the control so i created a dependency property of type Style and bound it to the Border like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:DrawingLayer}" >
 ...
   <Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
       <Border x:Name="PART_AreaSelector" Style="{Binding AreaSelectorStyle}" BorderBrush="#FF3399FF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#55ADD8E6"  />
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In the window where i use the control i try to define its style this way:

```
<cc:DrawingLayer.AreaSelectorStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>          
    </Style>
</cc:DrawingLayer.AreaSelectorStyle>
```

But it seems that the style is not applied. No property reflects the values in the style.

Can someone point out what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "local" property values assigned in

```
<Border ... BorderBrush="#FF3399FF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#55ADD8E6" />
```

have higher precendence than the values set by Style Setters.

You need to set a default Style for those values.

See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I did not post the entire control but i can assure the bindings point to TemplatedParent. Just to be sure i update the code with that bit so you can confirm.